# What is the safest way to use JavaScript for an AI programming game?

Tags: javascript

Being a programmer, I've always been a fan of AI programming games (think [RoboCode]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocode) even though I've never been really good at them. I've also been focusing on web development and JavaScript lately and looking to combine the two. This brings me to three issues:

1. How do I allow the user to program in JavaScript to create the AI? I imagine the user would be allowed to develop and test their AI from the webpage kind of like jsFiddle allows you to edit and run JavaScript.
2. How do I prevent the user from cheating? I can hide most of the internals of the game engine from the JavaScript but is there a way to prevent the user's js from accessing the DOM, window or AJAX queries (since they shouldn't need them)?
3. How do I safely test the user's code server-side? Do I need some special server JavaScript like node.js?

The competition will be turn based with the AI only needing to return a single action each turn (no need for timers). It will also be a high score based competition so the AIs will not be competing against each other directly.

Comment: The points of this question are exceptionally broad. How about you try one way to implement this game, and then share where you get stuck or when things go wrong.

Comment: I'm very confused with this question. 2.) indicates that you'd be running the game client side, but 3.) makes it sound like you want the game to run server side.

Comment: I actually started making this exact same game in JavaScript awhile back.  I never finished the project, but I started down the path of using a sandbox for the code to run in.

Comment: I would need to allow the user to test their code and also for the server to run the code to record high scores. I don't even know where to begin without advice on these issues. The main question is how to execute and safely limit user submitted javascript.